# Set different logging level between root and 3rd party module (pypsexec)

Tags: python, logging, psexec

I have some code that creates a root logger that saves messages on disk. Pretty standard.
My code uses the `pypsexec` module which tends to be too verbose, and I'd like to be able to:
1- Continue to create logging messages of my own as INFO
while
2- Suppressing any logging from pypsexec that is less than WARNING

How would I achieve that?

The documentation from pypsexec mentions that I should use something like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("pypsexec")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set to logging.INFO if you don't want DEBUG logs
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - '
                              '%(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

However, I already have a logger object that I have created as a root logger.
I'm not sure how to keep my root logger that logs my debugging messages as INFO, while restricting the messages logged by pypsexec that are WARNING and up?

--

I've also tried:

```
import logging
from pypsexec.client import log as psexec_logger
psexec_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

But I'm still getting pypsexec logs like this sample:

```
12/23/2022 03:19:20 PM - INFO     Initialising connection, guid: c7745e58-b06e-4db4-b6de-b11fa0293f13, require_signing: True, server_name: xxxxxx.xxx.xxx, port: 445
12/23/2022 03:19:20 PM - INFO     Initialising session with username: domain\useraccount
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. The issue was that the logged messages weren't actually coming from pypsexec, but instead from a package that pypsexec was using. I had to trace the code to figure out that smbprotocol was generating verbose messages.

All I had to do is:
`logging.getLogger('smbprotocol').setLevel(logging.WARNING)`